# ToLower() not lowercasing string?

Tags: c#

```
 List<string> expectedResult = new List<string> { "article i", "article ii", "article iii" };

 string result = Selenium.GetText("result_list");
 if (expectedResult.Any(result.ToLower().Contains))
 {
    // do something
 }
```

I get `result = "Article I"`, but `expectedResult.Any(result.ToLower().Contains)` returns false. Not sure why `ToLower()` is not working?

Can anyone review my work, and let me know if I'm doing things right here?

Comment: The text that you're getting implies that it will be a list of results.  Are you sure you're getting a single string `"Article I"`?  Are you sure it doesn't have extra whitespace?

Comment: yeah, I get a list of results, but the first time, I get result= Article I, the second time result = Article 2, etc. I have this in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more efficient not to use `ToLower`in this case but the `Contains` overload that takes a `StringComparer`.

The reason is that `ToLower` will create a (temporary) copy of the original string wheras the `Contains` overload won't:

```
if (expectedResult.Contains(result, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
{
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
List<string> expectedResult = new List<string> { "article i", "article ii", "article iii" };

string result = Selenium.GetText("result_list");
if (expectedResult.Contains(result.ToLower()))
{
   // do something
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is working as expected, your string from Selenium must be different.

**Test case producing a match:**

```
List<string> expectedResult = new List<string> { "article i", "article ii", "article iii" };
string result = "Article I";
if (expectedResult.Any(result.ToLower().Contains))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Contains");
    // do something
}
```